# Editing others' questions: etiquette issue with partially off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, editing, off-topic

The quidelines for editing say **don't change the meaning**. And it's reasonable and just. But what about questions like this one: ["Should I buy webcam of 720p or VGA quality?"](https://superuser.com/questions/347116/should-i-buy-webcam-of-720p-or-vga-quality)

The first part, where the user asks whether he will benefit from 720p webcam on 64 kbps network, is on-topic and useful. The second part is a shopping question and obviously off-topic.

Now, should I just edit the post, killing the second part and changing the meaning, or flag the question or just comment and ask the user to do the editing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just did what you proposed at the time you were writing this.

> Now, should I just edit the post, killing the second part and changing the meaning, or flag the question or just comment and ask the user to do the editing?

- You're not changing the meaning. You're just removing the part that's off-topic. If the question had been posted without these models, it would have been fine.
- The other part is a valid question, in my opinion. If a question can be saved by editing it, **just do it**. You're also doing the OP a favor. Sometimes users don't know how to word a question perfectly, and if you can do it for them, why not?
- Especially changing the meaning of shopping recommendations is allowed if they could be closed as "too localized" or "off-topic" or "not constructive" otherwise. Actually, it happens quite often here.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new here so I thought I'd better ask. Also, considering how swiftly this question was closed, some disagree with us here, thinking it's better to nix it than salvage what's possible.

Comment: It's easier to click "close" than edit it, sometimes. With some very low quality content, I'm also tempted to flag for deletion rather than trying to fix what's possible. Note that people aren't *forced* to make such edits and the close votes were fairly cast.. at least for the shopping part.

Comment: I'm a strong proponent of editing that doesn't change meaning (including removing it) but I also view this as the one exception.  I always leave a comment explaining the rationale, and the OP has the option of reverting (at their peril).