# Editing "on hold" question

Tags: discussion, editing, on-hold

The question

- https://superuser.com/questions/612281/reason-for-unexpectedly-shutdown-with-unexpected-symbols

by unregistered user was put on hold with "unclear what you are asking" as reason.

For me it's perfectly clear: user's Win7 occasionally has text appearing by itself in input fields and then starts shutdown process, again by itself.

Should I edit the question so it'd be (I hope) more clear to others? What is current policy about editing "on hold" questions by someone other than the author?

Comment: Related: [Editing others' questions: etiquette issue with partially off-topic questions?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3591/editing-others-questions-etiquette-issue-with-partially-off-topic-questions?rq=1).  In general, I'd say the same etiquette applies here as if you were to edit any other user's question/answer.  That being said, in this very specific case, I doubt you can shine any additional light on the user's question without any additional input from him/her.

Comment: @Kreiri - If you feel you can make the question clear then modify the question. Thats the point of the question not being locked but in a hold status is to provide a period of time to clarify the question.  Your will be unable to provide the specific details requires to clarify the question.

Comment: @Ramhound - thanks, I submitted my edit.

Comment: I think it could be clearer if the user would be generally more descriptive.  "the text was entered into boxes that were (or were not) selected"   This occurs on any program, or only web based programs, or I have only seen it in specific programs.  This happened today or this has happened for months now. I dont have Macro tools or I do, ETC ETC.  Instead they toss up "What they see" as if were supposed to understand the frequency, the occurance, and without any understanding of the software or hardware involved.  I would not condemn such questions or questioners, I would expect more info.